# Ruby on Rails open a file as a skeleton and then write variables in certain places?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a "skeleton file" and specific areas for variables and I am trying to open that file, apply those variables and then save the file to another file.

Any idea of where I could start, I got file opening and writing down pat, but I am confused on the variable part.

Comment: do you want to achieve something like a mail merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to invent [ERB](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB.html)? :-)

Let's suppose you have this file (skeleton.erb)

> Hello, <%= name %>

Then this code

```
template = ERB.new(File.read("skeleton.erb"))
name = "Vasya"
puts template.result(binding)
```

will print this

> Hello, Vasya

Comment: So would I then just do my normal file open stuff, assign the variables, do the ERB replace stuff, and then use puts to another file? Or how does the "puts template.result(binding)" allow me to write the output to a file?

Comment: @Steven yes, of course, `template.result(binding)` returns a string. Do whatever you want with it.